# how to convert an html script into a .js file script

Tags: javascript, jquery

would like to place the script into a .js file  that opens already with

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    });
```

I have tried but it feel slike because im putting the onMouse over command into the html I don't think it will be possible?

```
    <head>
        <style>
            div > p {
                cursor: pointer;
            }
        </style>

        <script>
            var monkeySrc = "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/martin-berube/animal/256/monkey-icon.png";
            var lionSrc = "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/martin-berube/animal/256/lion-icon.png";
            var treeSrc = "http://totaltreeworks.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/Tree-256x256.png";
            var falconSrc = "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/jonathan-rey/star-wars-vehicles/256/Millenium-Falcon-01-icon.png";

            function changeImage(src){
                document.getElementById("myImage").src = src;
            }

        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="images">
            <img id="myImage" width="256" height="256">
        </div>

        <div>
            <p onmouseover="changeImage(monkeySrc)">Monkey are funny!</p>
        </div>

        <div>
            <p onmouseover="changeImage(lionSrc)">Lions are cool!</p>
        </div>

        <div>    
            <p onmouseover="changeImage(treeSrc)">Trees are green!</p>
        </div>

        <div>
            <p onmouseover="changeImage(falconSrc)">Falcons are fast!<p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: do i have to id each div and call it from the .js file instead?

Comment: Your code works: http://codepen.io/skarllot/pen/pJXrar

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: You need to do this with jQuery?

Comment: i just want to place the script into a file .js file instead but it stops working wen placing it inside $(document).ready(function() {

Comment: This happens because you're wrapping global functions within `$(document).ready(function() { ...})`. Rather attach the events with JS, without inline attrubutes. A quick-fix would be to pull the globals out of `ready`.

Answer (score 1):

If you were to take your existing JavaScript and place it in an external file, it would work just fine. It would work because all of your variables and your function would be in the global scope.

Going one step further you'll want to move those `onmouseover` event handlers into the JavaScript itself.

Given a small change to your current HTML and assuming jQuery you could do something like the following:

`<p data-kind="monkey">Monkey are funny!</p>`

then

```
var urlMap = {
  monkey : 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/martin-berube/animal/256/monkey-icon.png'
...
};

$('p').on('mouseover', function () {
  var kind = $(this).data('kind');
  var url = urlMap[kind];
  changeImage(url);
});
```

which you would then be able to wrap in the `$(document).ready`, the shorthand for which is just `$(function () { /* The code from above here */ });`

Comment: ok, seems intresting will try it. how does this script target the div called images?

Comment: This particular script calls your `changeImage` function that targets the images div.

Comment: not producing the correct result. the four texts once hovered changes the image in the standalone div with the id="myimage"

Comment: I've provided a pretty detailed answer but it's not a copy paste solution. You'll need to use your developer skills to get the exact result you want. Take this answer as a guide.

Comment: is it better i learn jquery? not getting anywhere so far reading up on jquery site for functions to use targeting the myimage.

Comment: $('#myImage') Is how you select the item with the Id "myImage".

Answer (score 0):

You would need to bind the event handlers programmatically from within the .js file. jQuery would make this very simple and allow you to use arbitrary CSS selectors, but you can do the same in pure JS using e.g. `document.getElementById` and `document.addEventListener`.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the function to the event using Javascript addEventListner

1- Add id attribute to each of your paragraphs tags

```
   <p id="p1"> .....</p>
```

2- Grab a variable that points to each of those

```
var p1 = document.getElementById('p1');
```

3- add event listner

```
p1.addEventListener("mouseover", changeImage(monkeySrc));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put your javascript code in another file and replace `<script>...</script>` with `<script src="javascriptcodefilename.js"></script>` in your HTML file, it still works as intended.

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/waLqxz

Answer (score 0):

It might be cleaner to add all of your urls to an array where the key is the name of the link, so you would have something like urls['lionSrc'] = "www.xyz.com";...

then in your changeImage function you would do document.getElementById("myImage").src = url[src];

this way you could even check to see if the image exists already, and if not, show an "image not found" icon.